# Django - Model best practice when fields need to be repeated

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model where some fields could be repeated between 0 and 5 times for the same object.

`models.py`:

```
class FusionTableLayer(models.Model):
    layer_name = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    condition1 = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    condition2 = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    condition3 = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    condition4 = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    condition5 = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    option1 = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    option2 = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    option3 = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    option4 = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    option5 = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    option6 = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    ...etc
```

My question is it better to create a second model with the fields that could be duplicated and use a `ForeignKey` to link them?

`models.py`:

```
class EzApp(models.Model):
    layer_name = models.SlugField(max_length=50)



class EzAppOptions(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey(EzApp)
    condition = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    option = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True
```

I know it looks neat like this, but I found it more complicated to adapt forms, views and template to works with a second models with `ForeignKey` relationship. For instance, I have to manage two different formsets in the same view. What would be the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**models.py**

```
class EzApp(models.Model):
    layer_name = models.SlugField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.layer_name

class EzAppOptions(models.Model):
    app = models.ForeignKey(EzApp)
    condition = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True)
    option = models.CharField('SQL Query Conditions', max_length=100, blank=True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.condition
```

**forms.py**

```
class EzAppForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EzApp


OptionFormset = inlineformset_factory(EzApp, EzAppOptions, 
    fields=('condition', 'option'), can_delete=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def view_name(request):
    form = EzAppForm()
    formset = OptionFormset(instance=EzApp())
    return render(request, "page.html", {
        'form': form, 'formset': formset
    })
```

**template.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {{ formset.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you add more than just code/file names to your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) and [inline formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) for dealing with situations like this.

Comment: It's not out of the question in the real world. Sometimes it makes sense to denormalize. Overnormalization for certain apps is the kiss of death for database performance.

Comment: Ah, misread the question. I agree with you – I thought the original poster didn't know how many conditions/options there could be.